# Both automatic and conditional routing Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

If the user access the site directly www.mysite.com the routes should transition to first product page of first category.

If the user copy paste url of a particular product. user should be navigate to that particular product page.

I need some directions how to go about it as when I copy a product url `www.mysite.com/Men/shirts` it navigate to default first category first product as per my transitionTo

My router.js looks like this

```
 MyApp.Router.map(function () {
   this.resource('categories', {path: '/'}, function () {
     this.resource('category', { path: '/:category_id'}, function () {
        this.resource('product', { path: '/:product_id' });
     });
   });
});
```

my categories route's after model look like this

```
afterModel: function(categories,transition){
       this.transitionTo('category',categories.get('firstObject'));
},
```

my category route after model looks like this

```
afterModel: function (category) {
        var self = this;
        self.transitionTo('product', category.get('products').get('firstObject'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably do the default transition from the Index Routes.

```
 MyApp.CategoriesIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   afterModel: function(model) {
    this.transitionTo('category',model.get('firstObject')); 
   }  
 });

 MyApp.CategoryIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   afterModel: function(model) {
    this.transitionTo('product', Em.get(model, 'products.firstObject')); 
   }  
 });
```

Child resources/routes inherits parent's model since this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4246). You can use `this.modelFor` if you are using older version

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/felalizo/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example following your routing structure,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viyagaga/1/edit

specific category: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viyagaga/1#/category/2

specific product: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/viyagaga/1#/category/2/product/4

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    this is all categories<br/>
    <ul>
    {{#each category in model}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to "category" category.id}}
        id:{{category.id}}&nbsp;name:{{category.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category">
    this is category {{model.name}}<br/>
    with products:<br/>
    <ul>
    {{#each product in model.products}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to "product" product.id}}
        id:{{product.id}}&nbsp;name:{{product.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product">
    this is product:<br/>
    {{model.name}}<br/>

  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
   this.resource('categories', {path: '/'}, function () {
     this.resource('category', { path: 'category/:category_id'}, function () {
        this.resource('product', { path: 'product/:product_id' });
     });
   });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo("categories");
  }
});

App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(){
    return allCategoriesData;
  }
});

App.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return allCategoriesData.findBy("id",parseInt(params.category_id,10));
  }
});

App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
   return this.modelFor("category").products.findBy("id",parseInt(params.product_id,10));
  }
});

var allCategoriesData = [
  {"id":1,"name":"Category1",
   "products":[
     {"id":1, "name":"product11"},
     {"id":2, "name":"product12"}
   ]
  },
  {"id":2,"name":"Category2",
   "products":[
     {"id":3, "name":"product21"},
     {"id":4, "name":"product22"},
     {"id":5, "name":"product23"}
   ]
  },
  {"id":3,"name":"Category3",
   "products":[
     {"id":6, "name":"product31"}
   ]},
  {"id":4,"name":"Category4",
   "products":[
     {"id":7, "name":"product41"},
     {"id":8, "name":"product42"},
     {"id":9, "name":"product43"},
     {"id":10, "name":"product43"}
   ]}
];
```

If you need to show each route on its own window without the corresponding master then the routing and `hbs` templates need to change as follows,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cajalosu/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    this is all categories<br/>
    <ul>
    {{#each category in model}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to "category" category.id}}
        id:{{category.id}}&nbsp;name:{{category.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="category">
    this is category {{model.name}}<br/>
    with products:<br/>
    <ul>
    {{#each product in model.products}}
    <li>
      {{#link-to "product" model.id product.id}}
        id:{{product.id}}&nbsp;name:{{product.name}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>

  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product">
    this is product:<br/>
    {{model.name}}<br/>

  </script>
```

**js**

```
....
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('categories', {path: '/'});
  this.resource('category', { path: 'category/:category_id'});
  this.resource('product', { path: 'category/:category_id/product/:product_id' });
});
....
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
   return allCategoriesData.findBy("id",parseInt(params.category_id,10)).products.findBy("id",parseInt(params.product_id,10));
  }
});
....
```

**EDIT** - *transition to first object of first category*

http://jsbin.com/felalizo/1#/category/1/product/1

Comment: This doesn't do the default transition to the ``first product page of the first category``